# Can i use multiple get request with same path and different parameter names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, request

I was wondering if I can have multiple get requests with the same path but with different parameter names?

Would they override each other?
Or should I organize my path differently?

```
router.get('/:id', functionA);
router.get('/:username', functionB);

functionA(id) {
    // return orders by id;
}

functionB(username) {
    // return orders by username
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to use both of these will conflict:

```
router.get('/:id', functionA);
router.get('/:username', functionB);
```

Since requests are matched in the order declared and both of these routes match every single top level URL, every single incoming request to this route will match the first one and it will handle all the requests.   Only if you use some algorithm inside `functionA` to determine which actual requests belong to it and then call `next()` on the request that don't belong to `functionA` would `functionB` ever get called.

And, even if you found a way to make this work using the above logic, it's just not a good way to design things.  You should make it clear from the structure of the URL which request handler a given URL is destined for.

I don't know the whole structure of your app or your overall URL design, but something like this would be a lot clearer and free of conflict at this router level:

```
router.get('/id/:id', functionA);
router.get('/user/:username', functionB);
```

Comment: but I can have a different type of request method with different parameter names right?

Comment: @AhmetK - Yes, different methods are matched separately so they will not conflict.  So `app.get("/:id", ...)` and `app.post("/:whatever", ...)` will not conflict.  Make sure you're using the appropriate method for the type of operation through and not just distorting the method used to work-around this issue.